# How to backup and restore data in Titan-Server (with Cassandra and Elastic Search) without sstableloader

Tags: graph, cassandra, backup, restore, titan

I have the Titan server, with Cassandra, installed here, with multiple keyspaces configured. 
I've read many threads about how to back up and restore a keyspace, but all talk about using sstableloader.

However, I didn't find this tool, since the Titan installation I've used came with Cassandra, and there is not an exclusive bin folder for Cassandra on it.

I wonder how do I backup and restore a keyspace with these conditions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is just separately download the version of Cassandra compatible with the one that packaged with your Titan version.  I routinely do that to get nodetool and the cassandra-cli.